# Unity:Stop camera follow player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am following Survival Shooter unity tutorial and in the tutorial the down given code is used to make the camera follow the player.The code is working but how can i alter it so that it stops following the player at a given X and Y point.

**code**

```
public Transform target;            // The position that that camera will be following.
public float smoothing = 5f;        // The speed with which the camera will be following.

Vector3 offset;                     // The initial offset from the target.

void Start ()
{
    // Calculate the initial offset.
    offset = transform.position - target.position;
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on the offset from the target.
    Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;

    // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current position and it's target position.
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply stop updating his position:

```
private bool followPlayer = true;
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if(followPlayer){
        // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on the offset from the target.
        Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;

        // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current position and it's target position.
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Change the value of `followPlayer` to `false` and it will stop following

Answer (score 2):

To determine if the player is at given point, you need to check distance between the player and the point, e.g:

```
public Transform target;                // player position
public Transform stopingPoint;          // stopping point position
public double tolerance;                // the "radius" of stopping point

private bool followPlayer = true;

    ...

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if(!followPlayer)
        return;
    followPlayer = Vector3.Distance(target.position, stopingPoint.position) <= tolerance;

    ...
```